# How to send exception and return a value in the same method in java

Tags: java, exception, finally

I know it's not possibile throw exception and return a value in the same method, but i need to do this in somehow. I was thinking to use finally block to throw the exception and after return the value.
Something like:

```
public Type myMethod() {
try{
//some elaborations
return result;
} catch(MyException myException) {
    //do something 
    return result;
} finally {
if(myException != null) {
 throw myException ;
}
}
```

Is possible something like this, or how can i achieve this?

EDIT: Or can i split in different methods?

Comment: An exception thrown from a `finally` block discards any previously `return` or `throw` statement. Likewise, a `return` from a `finally` block discards any previously `return` or `throw` statement. If you want the exception and the value, then you can create a custom exception with a getter for the value, and throw that. See vsfDawg`s answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a custom exception that contains the original Exception as a cause and the current value.

A naive example:

```
public class ValueException<T> extends Exception {
  private T value;
  public ValueException(T value, Exception cause) {
    super(cause);
    this.value = value;
  }
  ... stuff ...
}
```

Within your method...

```
public Type myMethod() throws ValueException {
  Type result = null;
  try {
    //some elaborations
    return result;
  } catch(Exception e) {
    throw new ValueException(result, e);
  }
}
```

Some caller...

```
public Type getType() {
  try {
    return myMethod();
  } catch (ValueException e) {
    if (isGoodEnough(e.getValue()) {
      return e.getValue();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Type", e);
  }
```

Comment: The original error can be retrieved using `e.getCause()`. If you know its type you can rethrow that (using a cast, as `getCause()` returns `Throwable`). For example, `throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause();`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes. Create a class with 2 data types exception and return value.

```
public class ReturnExceptionResult {
    Object result;
    Exception ex;

...
}

public ReturnExceptionResult myMethod() {
    Object result;
    Exception ex;
    try{
        //some elaborations
        result=returnvalue;
    } catch(MyException myException) {
        //do something 
        ex=myException;
        result=returnvalue;
    }
        return new ReturnExceptionResult(result,ex);
}
```

Comment: In this way after returning the ReturnExceptionResult i have to decide if throw the exception or use the result, so again this is useless

Comment: In essence, it seems you're asking how to return normally and not return normally **at the same time**.  See the problem?   You can either return normally, with the exception object as part of the return value, or you can throw an exception, with the return value as part of the exception object.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I know it's not possibile throw exception and return a value in the same method, but i need to do this in somehow. ...
>
>
>
> ... Is possible something like this ... can i split in different methods?"*

The simplest approach would be to use a *class*.

```java
class Result<T> {
    T value;
    Throwable e;
}
```

Here is an example where *r* will always contain *"abc"*.

```java
Result x() {
    Result<String> r = new Result<>();
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(r.value = "abc");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        r.e = e;
    }
    return r;
}
```

You'll need to check whether *e* is *null*.

```java
Result<String> r = x();
if (r.e != null) System.out.println(r.e);
System.out.println("r.value = " + r.value);
```